# How do I compute the trace distance of matrices differing by a single row or column?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

I understand the definition of trace distance, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to explicitly compute it. In particular, say we have density matrices $\rho = [\alpha_{ij}], \rho'=[\alpha'_{ij}]$. Can we express their trace difference in terms of these coefficients? As a particular example, say $\rho, \rho'$ differ only on the $k$th row and column. Can (a nontrivial bound on) their trace difference be expressed in terms of $\{\alpha_{kj}, \alpha'_{kj}\}_j$?

Comment: Do you mean they differ both in the k'th row *and* column?  Did you try to write $\rho-\rho'$? What do you get?

Comment: Yes. (Since density matrices are Hermitian, isn't that implied?)

Comment: Ok.  And the 2nd and 3rd question?

Comment: Yes, I see a get a matrix that is nonzero only in the kth row and column. I am not sure how to derive the eigenvalues of such a matrix

Comment: Well, of course I would like the tightest possible bound...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W.l.o.g., assume $k=1$. Then, we have
$$
X=\rho-\rho' = \begin{pmatrix}0 & a_2^* &a_3^* & \cdots\\ a_2&0&0&\cdots\\a_3&0&0&\cdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \end{pmatrix}\ .
$$
That is, $X=|a\rangle\langle 1|+|1\rangle\langle a|$, with
$$
|a\rangle = a_2|2\rangle + a_3|3\rangle + \dots\ ,
$$
and thus, $\langle a|1\rangle =0$.

That is, up to rotation and normalization $|a|=\sqrt{\sum |a_k|^2}$, this can be rotated to your favorite two-dimensional subspace, where it is just a Pauli X matrix times $|a|$,
$$
X \cong |a|\,\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 &0\end{pmatrix}\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus \cdots\ .
$$
The eigenvalues of this are easily computed, and are $\pm |a|$ and a bunch of zeros.

Thus,
$$
\|\rho-\rho'\|_1 = 2|a| = 2\sqrt{\sum |a_k|^2}\ .
$$